# Push commit to 2 different remote branches?

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

I have two remote branches, branch A and branch B.

Consider the case where I checkout branch A, made a commit and pushed. Now, I want to push the same commit to branch B. These two branches are pretty different so I cannot user `rebase`, can I? Because if I do `git rebase` then I will rebase all changes from one branch to another, but I need to do it only with one commit. How can I do that?

PS. Now I do it in a stupid way: I checkout branch B, cherry pick last commit from branch A, and then push to B (remote). This way I don't like that I need to switch to branch B.

Comment: I believe you can do a git merge branch b with a while still keeping the branch b?

Comment: I don't find cherry picking stupid if you only need to "replicate" one commit.

Comment: Please confirm you mean 2 different remote branches and not 2 different remote repositories.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant essentially,  I meant two different remote repositories.

Answer (score 3):

That is what `git cherry-pick` is for.  Since your branches are very different from each other and you don't want to `merge` or `rebase` as it is only one commit, that is the option.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean two different repositories as you've stated then I think what you want is multiple remotes.

You can add a new remote at any time with `git add remote abc  git@github.com:msh/your_app_name.git`

Then you can push master to it with git push, e.g.

```
git push abc master
```

Normally, with github you use 'origin' for the initial remote, hence the common use of `git push origin master` (often shortened to `git push origin` or just `git push` , however you can add other remote at will and push to them with `git push [repo_name] [branch_name]`.  If you have multiple remotes you should always specifiy which one when pushing.